# How can I get the joint probability of new image and latent variable from generative model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I just learned that generative model tries to learn `p(x|z)p(z) = p(x,z)`.
But after I study some sample code of generative models such as VAE and GAN, I found that the output of model is the generated image `x`, which is a 2D matrix.
In my realization, the content of matrix means the probability of every pixel and the latent variable, is this right?
If it's right, is it possible to get joint probability `p(x,z)` between latent variables `z` and a whole image `x` from generative model?

Answer (score 0):

What a generative model is trying to learn is just p(x). p(x|z) = 1 if g(z) = x and 0 otherwise, because GANs and VAEs are deterministic mappings and therefore have 100% chance to map to the same target given the same input.

Extracting the probability of x is not an easy task though and depends on the approach. With GANs you can approximate this by sampling from the model. E.g. you sample 1000 images and see how often an image occured. Then this image has a probability of occurences / 1000. By the law of large numbers you will eventually recover the actual probability distribution of your generator this way.

If you want an exact way to calculate probabilities you can use FLOW networks like GLOW or RealNVP, which optimize for log(p(x)) directly and have a way to recover p(x).